# .replace() function doesn't swap characters correctly

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm writing a function that replace specific characters to other ones

```
public static String makeComplement(String dna) {
    if(dna.contains("A")|| (dna.contains("T") ||(dna.contains("G") ||(dna.contains("C") ) )) ){
        dna = dna.replace('A' , 'T');
        dna = dna.replace('T' , 'A');
        dna = dna.replace('G' , 'C');
        dna = dna.replace('C' , 'G');

        System.out.println(dna);
    }
    return dna;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ex ="GTACTCC";
    System.out.println(ex);

    makeComplement(ex);
}
```

it replaces the T in A & the C in G but keeps A & G the same.

Comment: You replace A-->T and T--A so the result is A-->A same for G.

Comment: Output: GAAGAGG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does.

```
dna = dna.replace('A' , 'T'); // replaces As with Ts
dna = dna.replace('T' , 'A'); // replace Ts with As (including the As that 
                              // were replaced with Ts)
dna = dna.replace('G' , 'C'); // replaces Gs with Cs
dna = dna.replace('C' , 'G'); // replace Cs with Gs (including the Gs that 
                              // were replaced with Cs)
```

If you want to swap As with Ts and Gs with Cs, you should probably use some intermediate letters:

```
dna = dna.replace('A' , 'X');
dna = dna.replace('T' , 'A'); // only original Ts will become As 
dna = dna.replace('X' , 'T');
dna = dna.replace('G' , 'Y');
dna = dna.replace('C' , 'G'); // only original Cs will become Gs
dna = dna.replace('Y' , 'C');
```

EDIT: As Mike commented, you can do this replacement much more efficiently without the `replace` method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (dna.length());
for (char c : dna.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == 'A')
        sb.append('T');
    else if (c == 'T')
        sb.append('A');
    else if (c == 'G')
        sb.append('C');
    else if (c == 'C')
        sb.append('G');
} 
dna = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanks @Eran didn't thought about that, I'm new to programming

Comment: Using this will replaces all `X`s with `T`s and all `Y` with `C`s, you should probably use a character that should not occur in a normal string e.g. the null char `'\0'`

Comment: @Lino well, for a String that represents DNA, a "normal" String will only contain A,T,G & C.

Comment: @Eran oh, I didn't realize that we're doing gene manipulation here, nvm then ;)

Comment: Calling `String.replace()` 6 times seems excessive since it looks at every character. I'm sure this OP's question is an academic exercise, but in the real world that likely won't be performant.

Comment: @Mike good point. It would probably be more efficient to iterate over the String once and construct the new String as we encounter the characters.

Comment: @Eran & Mike since you are discussing about efficiency how can I iterate over the String just once ?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `String.contains` and/or `String.replace` potentially scans the entire string, so calling it multiple times could be costly for very long Strings.

Why not do all the replacements in a single pass:

```
// Copy the original DNA string to a new mutable char array
char[] dnaCopy = dna.toCharArray();

// Examine each character of array one time only and replace
// as necessary
for(int i = 0; i < dnaCopy.length; i++) {
  if(dnaCopy[i] == 'A') {
     dnaCopy[i] = 'T';
  }
  else if(dnaCopy[i] == 'T') {
     dnaCopy[i] = 'A';
  }
  else if(dnaCopy[i] == 'G') {
     dnaCopy[i] = 'C';
  }
  else if(dnaCopy[i] == 'C') {
     dnaCopy[i] = 'G';
  }
}

// Now you can do whatever you want with dnaCopy: make a new String, etc
```

This approach should be much more performant for long strings, and could potentially scale up using a divide and conquer approach (i.e. you could have 2 threads working on one half of the array at the same time).